# How do I compare a given variable list with an infinite list to find the first non-occurring variable in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

hoping for some help on this one with my newbie Haskell code.

I'm trying to compare an input list of variables with an infinite list of variables

```
input = ["a", "b", "x"]
variables = ["a", "b", "c", "d", ... "a1", "b1", ... and so on]
```

I'd like to find **the first non-occurring variable in the input list**, in this case it should be "c".

I think the right way to go about it is using a filter...

```
ourFilter :: [Var] -> [Var] -> [Var]
ourFilter p [] = []
ourFilter p (x:xs) | matches x = x ourFilter xs
                   | otherwise = ourFilter xs

matches :: Var -> Bool
matches n = n `elem` variables
```

...but I'm getting the two errors thrown before compilation and I can't get my head around them:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘([Var] -> [Var] -> [Var])
                                -> [Var] -> [Var]’
              with actual type ‘[Char]’
• The function ‘x’ is applied to two arguments,
  but its type ‘[Char]’ has none
```

Can somebody help to explain what on earth is going on? Is this the right way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `x ourFilter xs` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3):

List difference `\\` can subtract a finite list from an infinite list:

```
> import Data.List
> head $ [1..] \\ [1,2,3,5,7,9]
4
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a colon:

```
... = x : ourFilter xs
        ^
```

You also need to pass `p` again on each recursive call:

```
... | matches x = x : ourFilter p xs | otherwise = ourFilter p xs
                                ^                            ^
```

There are other problems (for example, the fact that `p` isn't ever actually used seems like a red flag), but this will get it compiling so that you can play with it and fix them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should enumerate over the infinite list, and for each item check if it is a member of the list. If that is not the case, then return that value; otherwise recurse on the tail of the list. This thus looks like:

```
ourFilter :: [Var] -> [Var] -> Var
ourFilter input = go
    where go (x:xs)
        | x `elem` input = …  -- (1)
        | otherwise = …       -- (2)
```

Where I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise. For (1) you make recursive all to `go` with the tail of the list; and for (2) you return the variable, since that is the first one that does not occur.

One can turn this function into a function that uses `foldr` with:

```
ourFilter :: [Var] -> [Var] -> Var
ourFilter input = foldr f undefined
    where f x y | x `elem` input = …  -- (1)
                | otherwise = …       -- (2)
```

here `y` is the result of making a recursive call to the tail of the list.